# included files are missing in entityreference module

Tags: entities

I'm using D7.

I've just setup [Recruiter Features module](https://drupal.org/project/recruiter_features) with bunch of dependent modules, on my existing website. It seems Recruiter module is working fine but now I'm getting strange warnings about missing files in [Entityreference module](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) and vast majority of my views are not showing up on the website:

> Warning: include_once(/home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/entityreference/entityreference.views.inc) 
>       [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in theme()
>        (line 957 of /home/mysite/public_html/includes/theme.inc).
>
> Warning: include(/home/mysite/public_html/sites/all/modules/entityreference/views-view-unformatted.tpl.php) 
>       [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>       theme_render_template() (line 1397 of /home/mysite/public_html/includes/theme.inc).

The strange thing is that `entityreference.views.inc` file is acctualy located in `.../entityreference/views/` folder.

To remedy this I just moved `entityreference.views.inc` to `.../entityreference/` folder. I also created blank `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` file and put that file to `.../entityreference/` folder.

That worked, I'm not getting any warnings, my views are working, but I'm not happy with that solution. Just want to know why is this happening and how can I fix it properly without hacking the module?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a bug report you should resolve in module's issue queue?..

Comment: Molot there is a chance that I overwrote, by mistake, `entityreference` module with other version. I checked all `entityreference` versions, and none of these versions have `views-view-unformatted.tpl.php` and `entityreference.views.inc` in root module's folder. I tried running `update.php` but that did not work.

Comment: Revert to backup?

Comment: No files backup, just db backup. :(